# What if using rel="dofollow" and rel="nofollow" together for a link?

Tags: seo, nofollow, hyperlink, rel, dofollow

How does google consider these links? for example :

```
<a href="url" rel="nofollow" rel="dofollow">text</a>
```

Is it a `dofollow` link or `nofollow`? Which one has more priority over the other one?
I've used dofollow tags for backlinks of my website http://www.greenseo.ir , but I think it's an error!

Comment: It is invalid..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*No such thing as dofollow:*

The `dofollow` attribute does **NOT EXIST** in either `rel` or `meta`, this is due to the fact that by default both pages and links are considered `dofollow` unless you use `nofollow`.

[Meta follow](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) is not to be confused with dofollow `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`

Despite MASS belief follow and dofollow have nothing in common other than the fact they share a similar name, it has absolutely no bearing on passing of page rank. Meta Follow it simply informs search engines to discover content on the receiving end of links...

A page that is not indexed by Google or Bing will not pass juice period. Also, the usage of `content="noindex, follow"` is pointless because simply using `content="noindex"` informs search engines to follow links unless you use `content="noindex, nofollow"`.

---

*Rel dofollow is invalid markup:*

> [SOURCE](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)
>
> `<a href="#" rel="dofollow">test</a>`
>
> Bad value `dofollow` for attribute `rel` on element `a`: The string `dofollow` is not a registered keyword.d.

---

*Using duplicate REL is invalid markup:*

> [SOURCE](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)
>
> `<a href="#" rel="nofollow" rel="rel">test</a>`
>
> Error: Duplicate attribute `rel`.

---

*Example of valid markup using multiple `rel` values:*

> [SOURCE](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)
>
> `<a href="#" rel="nofollow me">test</a>`
>
> Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.

Answer (score 5):

The tag `rel="dofollow"` doesn't exist, it does nothing if anybody uses it.

Having two rel attributes in the same tag is an **error**, regardless of their value.

Comment: You *can*, however, have two rel *values* in the same tag, as long as you don't have more than one attribute, i.e. the following is valid: `<a href='url' rel='nofollow noreferrer'>text</a>`

Comment: that's one rel, not two.

Comment: but, yeah, I know. You can :)