# Prevent sending referrers when clicking links from my site with an exception for one domain

Tags: referrer, privacy-policy, content-security-policy

Let's admit that, for security / privacy reasons, I want to globally set my [referrer policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) to be `"no-referrer"`.

For instance, using Apache's `.htaccess`'s

```
Header always set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
```

IIS' `web.config`'s

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
             </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

etc., etc. In other words, I want this policy to be globally enforced, for every single webpage.

However, for one particular domain (say `https://validator.w3.org/`), I'd like to send the referrer (for instance, to use the convenient `url` `https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer`).

I could use the experimental [`referrerpolicy` attribute of links](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-referrerpolicy), but I don't know how well is that attribute supported. I don't know either if such an attribute can override the setting of the server.

The `link type 'norefferer'` attribute [seems to be well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=referrer), but I want to achieve the opposite!

How could I globally disallow the referer to be sent, except for links pointing to a particular domain?

Comment: If you were simply wanting to pass the referrer info for a particular external link, it can be done via redirecting to an intermediary page forced to http in htaccess. and changing the Referrer Policy on the intermediary page via a meta tag and adding a redirect via a meta refresh. 

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to achieve it, but it does work.

However with that said, it doesn't work for https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer

Comment: So basically you want to pass referral data only to one site - but block your domain from appearing as a referral source for all others? Not sure I completely understand your underlying intention, or what this does for you, but you might find your answer here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowAnchor

Comment: @BronwynV Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure I understand the technicals details of your proposition, but if it doesn't work for https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer, then indeed it is of no use to me.

Comment: @JoshSalganik Yes, you got that right: I want the referrer to be transmitted only when accessing a particular website / domain. My underlying intentions are essentially to use https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer : Click on the link, if the referrer was transmitted, we would have landed on https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwebmasters.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F109954%2Fprevent-sending-referrers-when-clicking-links-from-my-site-with-an-exception-for  This save the burden of giving the precise link for every page. I don't see how my problem is related to google analytics.

Comment: If the primary goal, in this case, is to test the URL at the W3C validator, then you can pass the URL to be tested directly in the URL parameter. eg. `https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.example.com/path/to/foo`.

Comment: @MrWhite Sure, and thanks. I was curious about a more general case, and, also, looking for a way not to edit some files by hand to change the link.

Answer (score 4):

**Method 2**

Following the concept of method 1 (below), I realised this could probably be done with just one technology and without reloading the current page. It's all done client side with plain javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://validator.w3.org" id="allowReferrer">Link that you do want to allow referrer to be passed to</a>
    <a href="http://w3.org">Link that you don't want referrer to be passed to</a>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('allowReferrer').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var metaRef = document.createElement("meta");
        metaRef.setAttribute("name", "referrer");
        metaRef.setAttribute("content", "origin");
        document.head.appendChild(metaRef);
        window.location.href=this.href;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(This code can definitely be improved - its just a proof of concept.)

Esentially there is an event listener on the `allowReferrer` ID which when triggered prevents the link to be followed, adds the referrer = origin meta tag to the head, then follows the link. Much tidier than method 1.

**Method 1**

I've just tested a rather convoluted solution, but its the only solution I can think of, and it did work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <?php
    if ($_GET["referrer"] == "true") {
        echo '<meta name="referrer" content="origin">';
        echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$_GET["location"].'";</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">';
    }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://example.com/?referrer=true&location=https%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org">Link that you do want to allow referrer to be passed to</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Link that you don't want referrer to be passed to</a>
</body>
</html>
```

(This code can definitely be improved - its just a proof of concept.)

When the page loads it looks for a query parameter called 'refferer', if that is not set to "true" then the referrer meta tag is set to 'no-refferer', but if it is set to "true" then the referrer meta tag is set to 'origin' and javascript is executed to redirect you to a location held in second query parameter called 'location'.

All links will normally be followed without passing any referrer information. If you want a link to allow the referrer to be passed, then you would create your link as

`[current URL]?referrer=true&location=[link which should be url encoded]`

for example

`http://example.com/test/some-page.php?referrer=true&location=https%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org`

Its definitely not pretty, but until there is good support for the referrerpolicy attribute on the anchor tags, it might be the only way. Before using this solution, I would urge you to ask yourself how important it is that you have this functionality, and is it worth it?

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's definitely convoluted, and involves **two** technologies (`php` and `JavaScript`), whereas I was definitely thinking that a "pure" `html` (with some tweaking in Apache / Nginx / Windows Server, eventually) would exist. That's definitely ingenious, though, I wouldn't have think of it.

Comment: Thans @Clément - perhaps there is an easier way but at this point in time, this is the only solution I can think of. I will keep pondering on it and get back to you if I come up with anything else.

Comment: @Clément I've added another method which might be more desirable. I'm using the network panel in Chrome dev tools to identify what header is being passed, and this seems to be working too.

Comment: @MrWhite … I don't think that's correct. Check https://blog.appcanary.com/2017/http-security-headers.html#referrer-policy/how , https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4110  , https://collinmbarrett.com/referrer-policy-header-nginx/  , etc.

Comment: Thanks again for sharing your idea, Josh. I'm not marking your answer as accepted because I do hope that some nicer solution exists, but you deserves that bounty.

Comment: @Clément - thank you. I am glad I was able to offer a working solution, but I appreciate the desire for a better solution, and I am equally interested to know the answer! Have you considered posting this at stackoverflow? I'd say it fits within the [community's remit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would think so, but thought I'll give webmasters.stackexchange.com a chance! I think this question fits more the bill here, and won't cross-post, but feel free to do it if you want to. Keep me informed `;-)` I slightly changed my question, making it more oriented toward overriding the server conf., so you could even ask your question without being a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I ended up posting the question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46982187/2657549 and offered a bounty for it, but it didn't raised much attention…

Comment: @Clément - how did you get on with this? Did you find a better solution?

Comment: Nope, I didn't find a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try in this way, although I am not sure if it's widely supported

```
 <a href="#link"  rel="referrer dofollow">link</a>
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "dofollow" value for the rel attribute](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/101250/14543)

Comment: So… The value `dofollow` does not exist, and moreover the solution simply do not work, so I don't think that's a really useful contribution. But thanks anyway.